# Issues installing FLASK (Full-sky Lognormal Astro-fields Simulation Kit)

Tags: linux, software-installation, python

I am trying to run FLASK on my PC and I have installed all the prerequisites which include HEALpix, GNU scientific library and CFITSIO.
But still I can't get my FLASK program to run, I have given the HEALDIR as the folder directory where I installed HEALpix.

But still when I run the command `./bin/flask example.config`, it doesn't run and shows that `there are no such directory`.

Maybe my HEALpix installation is flawed, but I can't test it.

The link to Github repository is as [here](https://github.com/ucl-cosmoparticles/flask)

Comment: Do you run `./bin/flask example.config` from the parent directory where FLASK is installed? By default the binary is installed to the `bin` directory of the same directory where `src` is. `example.config` is already in it. If you cloned the repository into your home directory, then you run the command from the root of the repository, typically from `cd ~/flask`. If your HEALPix installation where flawed, your FLASK `make` would fail with an error.